# Adding large Power values in Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am new to Objective C and iPhone development.

I'm working with a basic calculator. I want to add a large value in text field. How can I display large values like this : 6.67543 x 10^ -34 in Xcode? 
Thank you

Comment: large?  6.67543 x 10^ -34 is pretty tiny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set up a NSNumberFormatter with NSNumberFormatterScientificStyle and call stringFromNumber... However, the issue I think is going to be with the precision you are hoping to support requires a specialized framework. There might be one based on GNU MP Bignum library out there, but I don't know it off hand.

Answer (score 1):

Use Double data type. And then convert it into string then pass that string to your textField.

For eg:-

```
double result;
NSString *strResult = [[NSNumber numberWithDouble:result] stringValue];
```

It will give you exponential string.

And instead of a `UILabel` use `UITextField`.