# Power of decimal numbers

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Adding large Power values in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11877714/adding-large-power-values-in-xcode)

Am new to Objective C (iOS).  I want to find the power of decimal number but the method pow (x,y) crashes the program. 
It seems this method don't work for decimal number. I want to display this number in text field  6.6428 x 10^ -21.   how can i do that?  Thanks

Comment: Kindly mention the complete code.

Comment: show your code, paste the crash log. help us help you.

Comment: repost: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11877714/adding-large-power-values-in-xcode

Comment: You're really going to need to show us some code. As it stands, this question doesn't make much sense (why would `pow()` crash your application?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using decimals (floats) you need to use powf()

Comment: maybe he means NSDecimals or NSDecimalNumbers. who can tell…